# Can't make UART work in Bare Metal using STM32

Tags: esp32, uart, bare-metal, stm32f4discovery

I'm trying to transmit a message using UART in bare metal between an STM32F407 Discovery(bare metal) and a XIAO ESP32C3(ArduinoIDE) but I can't make it work, I don't receive anything.

I tried programming it between 2 STM32, It seems that I receive something in DR but it doesnt make much sense, I tried transmitting a 0 and got a 252 and when I sent a 7 I got a 128

Here is my init:

```
#define TX 9
#define RX 10

uart_init()
{
    RCC_AHB1ENR |= RCC_GPIOAEN;
    RCC_APB2ENR |= RCC_USART1EN;
    
    // configure usart pins
    GPIOA_MODER = REP_BITS(GPIOA_MODER, TX*2, 2, GPIO_MODER_ALT);
    GPIOA_AFRH = REP_BITS(GPIOA_AFRH, 1*4, 4, 7);
    GPIOA_OSPEEDR = REP_BITS(GPIOA_OSPEEDR, TX*2, 2, GPIO_OSPEEDR_HI);


    GPIOA_MODER = REP_BITS(GPIOA_MODER, RX*2, 2, GPIO_MODER_ALT);
    GPIOA_AFRH = REP_BITS(GPIOA_AFRH, 2*4, 4, 7);
    GPIOA_OSPEEDR = REP_BITS(GPIOA_OSPEEDR, RX*2, 2, GPIO_OSPEEDR_HI);

    
    USART1_CR1 = 0;
    USART1_CR1 |= USART_CR1_TE | USART_CR1_RE;

    //9600 baud
    USART1_BRR |= (273<<4);
    USART1_BRR |= 7; 

    //115200 baud
    // USART1_BRR |= (22<<4);
    // USART1_BRR |= 13; 

    USART1_CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;
}
```

My write function:

```
void write(){
    while (!(USART1_SR & USART_SR_TXE)) {};
    USART1_DR = 1; 
    while((USART1_SR & USART_SR_TC) == 0);
}
```

My read function:

```
void read(){
    while((USART1_SR & USART_SR_RXNE) == 0); 
    int c =  USART1_DR;
    printf("%d\n",c);
}
```

With the BRR I made(9600 bauds), the receiver gets incoherent messages but if I try a BRR for 115200 bauds it doesnt even work. I don't really know what else I could try.

Comment: Two things: once you are done configuring UART, verify (with debugger) that all bits in UART registers have meaningful values and nothing looks misconfigured. Additionally, it would be nice to see how you arrived at those timing values. I suspect timing values could be off (as one of theories). How did you calculate BRR?

Comment: I printed the registers and everything seemed fine. For my calculation, I used APB1_CLOCK (42Mhz) , I did : (42 000 000) / (16*9600), the result was 273,4375 so I did BRR = (273<<4) and BRR |= 7 (0.4375*16 = 7).